# Implementation of basic 2-pole low-pass filter

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, lowpass-filter

I know this question has been asked to hell and back from many people, and that it will probably get downvoted until it's deleted, but please bear with me.

I am designing a sound engine for one of my projects, which needs to support low-pass filtering (no other filtering required, so no need for extremely robust equalization or high-pass filters).

Unfortunately, I'm not exactly well-versed in DSP math (as I'm more a programmer than anything else), so this has been getting tricky.

What I've found by searching on the internet is a "1-RC and C filter" which is implemented as:

```
// Coefficient computation
// Cutoff and reso are [0,128) integers
c = 0.5^[(128-Cutoff) / 16.0]
r = 0.5^[( 24+Reso)   / 16.0]

v0 = (1.0 - r*c)*v0 - c*v1 + c*input
v1 = (1.0 - r*c)*v1 + c*v0
```

On the same website, I also found that c can be written frequency-wise with the formula

```
c = 2.0 * sin(Freq * pi/SampRate)
```

Since I'm only doing variable low-pass filtering with no resonance, this leads to

```
c = 2.0 * sin(Freq * pi/SampRate)
r = pow(0.5, 24 / 16.0) = 1 / sqrt(8) = ~0.3536
```

Since the sound engine is mostly MIDI-related, I've used the frequency cutoffs I've found elsewhere on the internet, which led to a relatively simple formula of

```
CutoffFreq = 250.0 * 32^x
```

Where x is bound to [0.0,1.0], which leads to a frequency range of 250Hz~8kHz.

However, this is where my issues start.

Let's assume that we're using a maximum cutoff frequency (that is, there should be no filtering on the data) and that I'm mixing at 44.1kHz.

```
c   = 2.0 * sin(8000.0 * pi/44100.0) = ~1.0791
r   = 8^(-0.5)                       = ~0.3536
      1.0 - r*c                      = ~0.6184
```

Now let's assume the input signal is a basic triangle:

```
Input[] = {0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2}
```

Applying the code above leads to

```
// Beforehand...
v0 = 0.0
v1 = 0.0

// 1st Sample [works okay]
v0 = 0.6184*0.0 - 1.0791*0.0 + 1.0791*0.0 = 0.0
v1 = 0.6184*0.0 + 1.0791*0.0              = 0.0

// 2nd Sample [incorrect]
v0 = 0.6184*0.0 - 1.0791*0.0 + 1.0791*0.2 = ~0.2158
v1 = 0.6184*0.0 + 1.0791*0.2158           = ~0.2329 [residual 0.0329]

// 3rd Sample [more than doubly incorrect]
v0 = 0.6184*0.2158 - 1.0791*0.2329 + 1.0791*0.4 = ~0.3138
v1 = 0.6184*0.2329 + 1.0791*0.3138              = ~0.4826 [residual 0.0826]
```

As you can see, this doesn't exactly work correctly.
In fact, judging from the sound of it, it's as though I had introduced a slight high-pass filter as well as increased resonance slightly.

As such, I was wondering if anyone could offer an explanation a more programming-related person could understand for computing low-pass filter coefficients and equations, as well as shed some light on how to properly implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your filter is a non-typical lowpass filter. The transfer function of your filter is

$H(z) = \frac{\beta^2}{1+(\beta^2-2\alpha)z^{-1}+\alpha^2z^{-2}}$

where $\alpha = 1-rc$, $\beta=c$.

In the example you use these values

$c = 2\sin(8000\pi/44100)$, $r = 8^{-0.5}$.

They give the following frequency response.

[image]

In the example where you step-by-step process the first samples of your triangular waveform it seems that you expect that input to pass through undistorted. Is that correct? if so, why do you expect this?

As an alternative you can use a 2nd order butterworth low-pass filter. Here http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt you find the expressions for the coefficients as well as the difference equation you have to implement.

Comment: Well, I would've expected that the highest frequency value I can get from the equation I found for MIDI cutoff would result in an undistorted output, as that's what it implies.

[EDIT: sorry, I didn't realize hitting Enter would stop <_<].
What's the difference between a Butterworth filter, a typical low-pass filter, and the filter I'm implementing a the moment?

Comment: The Butterworth magnitude response is monotonically decreasing from DC. There are no ripples nor overshoots. Furthermore, the Butterworth filter puts two zeros right at nyquist (fs/2). It costs a little extra but not much.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation of why you expect to see an undistorted output.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Butterworth filter also has a sharper cutoff (steeper roll-off) than your filter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

As for my explanation: Like I said, I'm a programmer, so I think of things differently. To make another example, think of it as changing the DC value: The signal is still exactly the same if you shift DC by 0.0. So I thought it'd be the same if I were to have no low-pass filtering by having the cutoff set at the absolute limit.

Comment: If your LPF has DC gain 0 dB then the further up in frequency you move the cutoff frequency the less effect you'd expect it to have on your input. Try to test your filter with the sequence of all ones [1 1 1 1 1 1 ....]. This should be passed through untouched and then [1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 ...] which should be removed or suppressed substantially. Your triangular waveform will only come trough untouched if your magnitude response is completely flat at 0 dB and your filter has linear phase (which is not the case for your filter either).

Comment: *nod* So basically, no matter what I do (unless I pass the original signal directly, or have a filter with a flat response with linear phase), the output signal will always differ from the original, so I should just try the Butterworth filter to see if it has any less discernible distortion?

Comment: I was going to say that unless your filter comes down to being a delay your triangular input will be 'distorted'. Maybe a better way to test your filter is to verify that it does what it is expected to do. Pass frequencies below the cutoff frequency and suppress frequencies above the cutoff frequency. Maybe test with pure tones, white noise or some sweep.

Comment: Well, that's just the issue.
Currently, the filter is working great in terms of suppressing frequencies above the cutoff. Unfortunately, it also appears to introduce some resonance into the output when using a high cutoff value, which is why I'm curious as to why [and how to fix it], from a programming POV, since all I want to do is suppress frequencies above the threshold.

Comment: That is why you should choose Butterworth, it does not have that resonance and it is better at suppressing frequencies above cutoff. If you insists in using your filter structure which is not standard you will have to understand the expression for the coefficients. Instead I suggest you switch to Butterworth and a 'standard' direct form implementation. I think that the Butterworth will give you a better LP filter for the same MIPS or maybe even less MIPS because your filter structure seems to require 4 multiplies pr sample.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. But about the multiplies: I thought Butterworth required five multiplies per sample? One for the input, two for the previous inputs, two for the previous outputs?

Comment: The Butterworth filter has two zeros at fs/2. The numerator can be put on the form $k(1-z^{-1})(1-z^{-1})=k(1-2z^{-1}+z^{-2})$. Therefore, only three multiplies are required in the direct form.

Comment: Ah, okay.
Thank-you very much for the information. n_n