# How do I make a two pole filter with resonance

Tags: lowpass-filter

I want a 40 dB/decade roll-off two-pole filter with resonance that does not peak when the cut off frequency is changed. I also want resonance to remain at a constant volume unless it is updated. @DanBoschen has got a basic blueprint which I am trying to follow but so far I don't completely understand everything.

This is the code so far, It has a problem that is preventing it from working The waveform will trough at 0. I have triple checked the algebra, (I'm not the best at algebra yet)

What is wrong with my code?

New code:

````
public class DynamicTwoPoleFilter implements ISimpleFilter {
    
    // instance variables
    private double cutoffFrequency;
    private double resonance;
    private double sampleRate;
    private double cutoffAmount;
    private double resonanceAmount;
    private double time;
    private double k;
    private double alpha;
    private double beta;
    private double gama;
    private double delta;

    // constructor
    public DynamicTwoPoleFilter(double cutoffFrequency, double sampleRate, double resonance) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.resonance = resonance;
        cutoffAmount = Math.sqrt(2) * Math.PI * this.cutoffFrequency;
        time = 1 / sampleRate;
        k = -2 * Math.PI * cutoffFrequency / 
                Math.tan(-2 * Math.PI * cutoffFrequency * time / 2);
        resonanceAmount = Math.pow(0.5, (24 + resonance * 0.25 * 128) / 16);
        delta = (Math.pow(k, 2) + 2 * cutoffAmount * k + 2 
                * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2));
        alpha = 2 * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2) / delta;
        beta = (4 * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2) - 2 * Math.pow(k, 2)) / delta;
        gama = (Math.pow(k, 2) - 2 * cutoffAmount * k + 2 
                * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2)) / delta;
    }

    // low pass filter
    @Override
    public double lowPass(double point) {
        
        double a = Math.pow(point, -1);
        double b = Math.pow(point, -2);
        
        return alpha * ((1 + 2 * a + b)/(1 + beta * a + gama * b));
    }

    // high pass filter
    @Override
    public double highPass(double point) {
        return point - lowPass(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCutoff(double cutoffFrequency) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        cutoffAmount = Math.sqrt(2) * Math.PI * this.cutoffFrequency;
        time = 1 / sampleRate;
        k = (2 * Math.PI * cutoffAmount) / 
                Math.tan((2 * Math.PI * cutoffAmount * time) / 2);
        delta = (Math.pow(k, 2) + 2 * cutoffAmount * k + 2 
                * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2));
        alpha = 2 * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2) / delta;
        beta = (4 * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2) - 2 * Math.pow(k, 2)) / delta;
        gama = (Math.pow(k, 2) - 2 * cutoffAmount * k + 2 
                * Math.pow(cutoffAmount, 2)) / delta;
    }
    
}
```
````

Comment: Greetings Edward! There is a lot of code here to read and debug which we don't typically do on this site, certainly not 4 1/2 pages of code as shown (3 to 4 lines max!). Your question would be greatly improved if you can extract your signal processing question more concisely with math and and graphics- Especially helpful would be if you could define what you mean by "modulate", what exact result you are expecting and the result you are getting and more specifically where you are having difficulty.

Comment: "Filter modulator" is not an established signal processing term.  If you could start by describing what you mean by that -- perhaps even tell us what you're really doing *with* a "filter modulator" -- then the road to sensible answers will be much shorter.

Comment: I have tried making the code more clear and removed some unnecessary code. What actually is wrong is the setCutoff code in both methods.

Comment: @DanBoschen While OP's code is excessive, "3 to 4 lines max" is overkill, we can surely handle more.

Comment: The setCutoff(double cutoffFrequency) is the code I need help with in TwoPoleFilter and ITFilter. The dynamic cutoff frequency works fine with Sinc and single pole filters, but I need a two pole with resonance filter that can be dynamically updated for my program.

Comment: Can you provide more specifics on the type of low pass filter you desire? Is this a simple 2 pole filter with 40 dB/decade roll-off and no peaking where you want to change the cut-off but not affect the pass-band amplitude? Or are there other features you are trying to do and how did you derive the algorithm you are now using?

Comment: All I need is a two pole filter with resonance. that can have its frequency dynamically updated without breaking. Peaking is okay because in the final program the audio is reduced to 1/4 of its amplitude.

Comment: Something similar to the filter on a Commodore 64.

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716  please update your question to describe the specific filter you want and what you want to change. "A two pole filter with resonance" is too vague and I personally I don't know anything about the filter on a Commodore 64. If you can provide a frequency response as an example showing any actual constraints you have that would really help (what if there is no peaking at all but a simple low pass filter, would that be ok, etc)--

Comment: I did find a link to the data sheet for the Commodore 64 SID in case someone else has the energy to go through and extract what the filter performance would be to be similar to this: http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6582_sid.pdf

Comment: Also where are some good places for me to read up on filters so I can start coding my own. all the ones I programmed were from other sources and the only ones I somewhat understand is the single pole and sinc filters.

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 I actually have a course starting this Friday that will go into detail on designing digital filters: you can find more details and the sign-up here: https://ieeeboston.org/event/digital-signal-processing-webinar/

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean about "resonance"? Do you mean [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFjJ.png)?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen something like the resonance on this two pole filter https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/implementation-of-basic-2-pole-low-pass-filter?rq=1

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 Then it looks like what I've shown, only my graphs are more "conservative" in the variance of Q.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirement of a 2 pole 40 dB/decade roll-off with peaking that doesn't change as the cut-off frequency is changed, A simple approach would be to map the analog two-pole filter given by:

$$H(s) = \frac{a^2}{s^2+ 2as+2a^2}$$

Where $a$ is related to the cutoff frequency using the relationship:

$$a = \sqrt{2}\pi f_c $$

(This results in two complex conjugate poles at $p = -a \pm j a$)

The digital filter is determined using the bilinear transform, with warping of the pole location by replacing the following with $s$ in $H(s)$ as follows:

$$s \leftarrow K \frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

With

$$ K = \frac{-2\pi f_c}{tan\bigg(\frac{-2\pi f_c T}{2}\bigg)}$$

Where $f_c$ is the desired cutoff frequency in Hz,

and $T$ as the sample duration or inverse of the sampling rate in Hz:

$$T = \frac{1}{f_s}$$

Leading to:

$$H(z) = \alpha \frac{1+2z^{^-1}+z^{-2}}{1+\beta z^{^-1}+\gamma z^{-2}}$$

With

$$\alpha = \bigg(\frac{ 2a^2}{K^2+2aK+2a^2}\bigg)$$

$$\beta = \frac{4a^2-2K^2}{K^2+2aK+2a^2}$$

$$\gamma = \frac{K^2-2aK+2a^2}{K^2+2aK+2a^2}$$

One possible implementation block diagram of H(z) using the Transposed Direct-Form II structure is shown below.

[image: Implementation]

For example, the following shows the comparative frequency of $H(s)$ and $H(z)$ with a sampling rate of 1 KHz and a cut-off frequency of 50 Hz:

[image: 50 Hz cutoff]

And with a cutoff of 100 Hz, where we see the stop band will have a zero at Nyquist (500 Hz) but the cut-off frequency will still track closely due to the pre-warping:

[image: 100 Hz cutoff]

Comment: Is p the cutoff frequency?

Comment: Also, using the above Two Pole filter as an example, Which formulas should be executed in the constructor, which should be executed in the setCutoff(cutoff) method and which should be set in the lowPass(point) method?

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 I updated it with complex poles for a cleaner cutoff ($f_c$ is the -3dB cutoff frequency). Do you know how to interpret the block diagram? That is the filter implementation that you can translate to your code.

Comment: I don't really know how to interpret the block diagram to tell the truth. Do the triangles mean multiply?

Comment: No worries- that is why I asked, yes the triangles are gains, and the $z^{-1}$ means a delay of one clock cycle. So the output would be your input multiplied by $\alpha$ + twice the last input multiplied by $\alpha$ + the input before that multiplied by $\alpha$ + the last output multiplied by $-\beta$ + the output before that multiplied by $-\gamma$

Comment: So given your sampling rate $f_s$ and your desired cutoff frequency $f_c$ you would compute the $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ coefficients and then use those values in your filter. If the cutoff changes, you change the coefficients accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124114/discussion-between-edward-eddy67716-and-dan-boschen).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in my original code, all I had to do was clamp values zero and one to never be above 1 and below -1. so it ends up that I did not need this filter.